# Rails has_one with multiple columns - has_many and has_one issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Trying to come up with a has_one association for this issue. I have two tables:

```
Ca:
  :id
  :serial
  ...
Cert:
  :id
  :ca_id
  :serial
  ...
```

There are many certs for a given cas.id but only one cert for a cas(:ca_id, :serial). I don't need the has_many association, but do need the has_one so that I may reference the certificate of the CA using ca.cert. I need the has_one to create something like the following query:

SELECT * FROM certs where ca_id = {ca.id} AND serial = {ca.serial}

To further illustrate the associations between a CA and certificates -

- A single CA HAS a certificate identifying itself
- A single CA HAS multiple certificates that it issues to end users
- A CA issues certificates based on its own sequence. For simplicity, starting at 1 (the CA's certificate will have serial 1, end users certificates issued by the CA will begin at 2).
- A certificate belongs to a CA by :ca_id and :serial
- Multiple CAs are stored. This means two certificates could have the same serial but belong to two different CAs.

[image: Illustration]

Why model it like this? Well, a cert-is-a-cert. Meaning structure and feature are similar whether the cert identifies a CA or an end user.

Seems like has_one would be straight forward but I've tried various approaches using scopes and such to no avail.

Granted I can, and have, created a 'cert()' method in the cas model but it just seems like an association should be possible.

Comment: My answer may be a bit off your question, why are you setting up your `Cert` model to both save the `id` & `serial` of its `Ca`. The ID would suffice.

Comment: @TheChamp - a CA HAS its own certificate. A CA ISSUES end-user certificates. Certificate serials are sequences based on a given CA, so multiple certs could have the same serial but would belong to different CAs. Given that a-cert-is-a-cert whether issued for a CA or issued by a CA I effectively have two types of certificates in the table.

Comment: Hmm, I doubt I get all of it... Doesn't it seem to be a more underlying problem in your model structure if you say you have two types of certs? You could also [check out STI](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/), which allows you to define different types of the same model.

Comment: Is the serial uniq in the certs table? If it is, you can create an association using the serial

Comment: Thanks for the edit, much clearer now, and Martin posted a nice solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can** define a has_one with a scope:

```
class Ca < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certs
  has_one :cert, ->{ joins(:ca).where('cas.serial = certs.serial')}
end

class Cert < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ca
end
```

now

```
Ca.first.cert
```

gives THE cert with the matching serial.
But is it more elegant or more Rails than defining:

```
class Ca < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certs
  def cert
    certs.where(serial: serial)
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice one, +1, is the joins(:ca) necessary?

Comment: Brilliant! This does what I'm looking for. You guys are great. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @TheChamp yes, without the `joins()`, Rails would just select from certs. The `joins()` makes the table `cas` available for the `where` clause.